# Maxima: suppress `linenum` in both input and output prompt

Tags: prompt, maxima

The Maxima documentation reads:

> Maxima automatically constructs a label for each computed expression by concatenating `outchar` and `linenum`.

http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_4.html#outchar

It describes how to customize the `inchar` and `outchar`, but there is always the line number included. I know this is useful for referencing expressions later, but when I am putting the post on e.g. StackOverflow, the line numbers aren't usually important, so I want to omit them.

(Also, this is purely cosmetic, but sometimes it occasionally makes the inputs misalign a little.)

Instead of this:

```
(%i9) 1 + 1;
(%o9)                                  2
(%i10) 2 + 2;
(%o10)                                 4
```

I want this:

```
(%i) 1 + 1;
(%o)                                   2
(%i) 2 + 2;
(%o)                                   4
```

How can I customize the Maxima prompt to suppress the line number?